# How to make a more professional search filter in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, filtering, searchview

I use the recyclerview filter

I want to show the ordering of the data on a more similar basis, not on the basis of id

For example

When I search the tree, the order is displayed like this

Data with id 1 - big tree

Data with id 2 - tree

While it's better to show this

1-tree

2-big tree

My filter method
Should I make some changes here?

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                String charString = constraint.toString();
                ArrayList<Tabir> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Tabir tabir : mArrayList) {
                    if (tabir.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {
                        filterList.add(tabir);
                    }
                }
                mFilteredList = filterList;

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "results=" + results);
            }
        };
    }
```